# different item style for items in listbox

Tags: google-apps-script

As listbox only accept string as items, is there a way to add items with different style? Is there any class to do this?
Ex:
Item1 in red
Item2 in green

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var tree = app.createTree();
tree.addItem(app.createTreeItem(
    app.createLabel("Tree Item 1").setStyleAttribute("color","green")));
tree.addItem(app.createTreeItem(
    app.createLabel("Tree Item 2").setStyleAttribute("color","red")));
```

**Edit:** Sorry you said List but I read Tree for some reason.

No, this cannot be done, because the underlying browser list widgets don't support it. It's possible to achieve something roughly similar using HtmlService and jQuery, but not in UiApp.

Comment: Thanks, I will try the class as your suggestion.